# Contacts and Activities "duplicated" with new IDs long after original is created

Tags: dynamics-365

In dbo.ContactBase and dbo.ActivityPointerBase the same records are clearly being inserted multiple times long after the original record was created. We have noticed that the issue has gotten much worse since we recently enabled Server-Side Sync but the issue existed before that change.

For example, a user may have created a contact in 2017, now in 2019 the contact is being "recreated" with new ContactIds but all displayed fields are identical and the Created By is the same 2017 user. In some cases the users may have gone on to a different department and no longer interact with CRM in any way, yet new Contacts are showing up "Created By" them.

We do use Kingswaysoft for some updates and inserts from SSIS and we are on-premise. I have not been able to find anything in the Kingswaysoft packages that would insert new records into these tables. On the duplicate contacts, it appears that dbo.ContactBase.VersionNumber is the only value changing between records. Please let me know what code I can provide to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I rember that the Outlook Client could create a lot of duplicates. If you reinstall it in the wrong order or if you install it on a new WorkStatation. Can you confirm, that all users only using Server Side Sync and that the Outlook CLient is Uninstalled on all CLient Computers? https://www.concurrency.com/blog/may-2017/avoiding-duplicates-with-the-d365-crm-outlook-ad

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any duplicate detection rules enabled for the contacts entity?  I would recommend getting that setup first if not.

It would at least address the symptom while you're trying to find the cause of the problem, but most likely the culprit is the Outlook addin like [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11451988/martin) indicated.